# How can I extract Chinese symbols from text

Tags: text-processing

I am unable to post Chinese text symbols here but basically I just want to remove all the lines that do not contain at least one Chinese symbol.

http://pastebin.com/au8zeATC

How can I extract that so it looks like

http://pastebin.com/5YPvzGJT

Comment: Please leave a response if this is not a duplicate because I also marked it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your data in the file `data` and run:

```
perl -CSD -lne 'print if /\p{Han}/' data
```

See also:

- [Extract only chinese characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212372/extract-only-chinese-characters)

Comment: Thanks man. How would I do this for a while folder and subfolder? I have "Chinese" folder and want everything Chinese inside that dumped into "Chinese.txt"

Comment: @Teddy291, try `find path-to-folder -type f -not -name Chinese.txt -print0 | xargs -0 perl -CSD -lne 'print if /\p{Han}/' >Chinese.txt`

Comment: find Envir -type f -not -name Chinese.txt -print0 | xargs -0 perl -CSD -lne 'print if /\p{Han}/' > Chinese.txt
Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at -e line 1, <> line 2.
xargs: perl: exited with status 255; aborting

Comment: @Teddy291, try `find path-to-folder -type f -not -name Chinese.txt -print0 | xargs -0 perl  -C2 -MEncode -lne '$_ = decode("UTF-8", $_, Encode::FB_QUIET); print if /\p{Han}/' >Chinese.txt`

Comment: That posted three lines that contain Chinese but there should be hundreds

Comment: well, you have an invalid utf8. which encoding do you use? try https://chardet.github.io/ for detecting

Comment: I am not sure. I can't get that working but I just reinstalled CentOS so I am using the default.

Comment: A file encoding doesn't depend on your system. where do you get your files?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to match is anything within one of the [Unicode blocks for Chinese characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs). This means you need to use something that supports Unicode, and then match any line that has a character in it that falls within one of those blocks.

Unfortunately, `grep` does not seem to support Unicode very well out of the box. However, Python 3 does, so if you have that, the following script will do what you need:

```py
import sys

sys.stdout.write("".join( 
   line for line in sys.stdin.readlines()
   if any(    0x4e00 <= ord(ch) <=  0x9fd5    # CJK Unified Ideographs
          or  0x3400 <= ord(ch) <=  0x4dbf    # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A
          or 0x20000 <= ord(ch) <= 0x2a6d6    # Extension B
          or 0x2a700 <= ord(ch) <= 0x2b73c    # Extension C
          or 0x2b740 <= ord(ch) <= 0x2b81d    # Extension D
          or 0x2b820 <= ord(ch) <= 0x2cea1    # Extension E
          for ch in line)))
```